# Writing a program taking LLVM IR file as a Command line argument

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a main.cpp file for testing LLVM IR Command line argument .

I am using llvm version : 6.0.1

```
#include<iostream>
#include <llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeReader.h>
#include <llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeWriter.h>
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ErrorOr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <llvm/Support/Error.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
using namespace llvm;
using namespace std;

static cl::opt<string> input(cl::Positional, cl::desc("Bitcode file"), cl::Required);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "LLVM IR to Bytecode \n");
LLVMContext context;

ErrorOr<std::unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer>> mb = MemoryBuffer::getFile(input);
if (error_code ec = mb.getError()) {
    errs() << ec.message();
    return -1;
}
 ErrorOr<std::unique_ptr<Module>> m=parseBitcodeFile(mb->get()->getMemBufferRef(), context);
  if (error_code ec = m.getError())
{
    errs() << "Error reading bitcode: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    return -1;
}
return 0;
}
```

I got this error :

> error: ‘class llvm::Expected >’ has no member named ‘getError’
>      if (error_code ec = m.getError())

I google many times but I do not found answer any where. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: I do not see a `getError` method in that classes interface [as described in the docs](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Expected.html)

Comment: did you mean to call `takeError?`?

Comment: @CoryKramer, Yes, there is no getError member so what is the alternative option for it?

Comment: @Borgleader, I tried  takeError(), but it is showing : 'error: conversion from ‘llvm::Error’ to non-scalar type ‘std::error_code’ requested'

Comment: I'm assuming you found this code somewhere and it was written with an older version of LLVM. Seems getError was removed, and there is now takeError which seems like a likely replacement. The return type is different yeah you probably need to change that too.

Comment: @Borgleader, I found one solution, but I do not able to implement it as it is function, declaring function inside function is not valid. Could you suggest me how to implement it?                                                                                      
`Error takeError()
    {
     #if LLVM_ENABLE_ABI_BREAKING_CHECKS
     Unchecked = false;
     #endif
     return HasError ? Error(std::move(*getErrorStorage())) : Error::success();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The above error was due to change in LLVM API over a time. Change module reader functions to return an `llvm::Expected <T>` []https://reviews.llvm.org/D26562 
. This class parallels ErrorOr, but replaces error_code with `Error`. Since Error cannot be copied, this class replaces getError() with `takeError().`

So above code changes to :

```
Expected<std::unique_ptr<Module>> m = parseBitcodeFile(mb->get()->getMemBufferRef(), context);
    if (std::error_code ec = errorToErrorCode(m.takeError())) {
    errs() << "Error reading bitcode: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    return -1;
  }
```